# Jquery Range Slider with Image Swap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a range slider that can swap to different images when the user drags the slider. I created a range slider, but i do not know how to take the value of the slider, and then show the corresponding image for the value selected.

Here is a visual example of my goal. [image: Visual Range Slider showing the different sizes of banners available.]

```
    <input type="range" min="0" max="9" value="0" step="1" onChange="sliderChange(this.value)" />
<br /><br />

slider value = <span id="sliderStatus">0</span>
```

Any help would be appreciated on how to achieve this.

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/stinkytofu3311/pen/RpmMRy?editors=1010)

Thank You

Comment: I guess Sachin Bahukhandi gave you the right anwer. I had overlooked that the slider is an input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var imageUrl = new Array();

        imageUrl[0] = 'https://static.pexels.com/photos/39517/rose-flower-blossom-bloom-39517.jpeg';

        imageUrl[1] = 'https://static.pexels.com/photos/36764/marguerite-daisy-beautiful-beauty.jpg';

        imageUrl[2] = 'http://cdn2.stylecraze.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/dahlia-flowers.jpg';

        imageUrl[3] = 'https://static.pexels.com/photos/39517/rose-flower-blossom-bloom-39517.jpeg';

        imageUrl[4] = 'https://static.pexels.com/photos/36764/marguerite-daisy-beautiful-beauty.jpg';

        imageUrl[5] = 'http://cdn2.stylecraze.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/dahlia-flowers.jpg';
       
$(document).on('input change', '#slider', function() {//listen to slider changes
    var v=$(this).val();//getting slider val
   $('#sliderStatus').html( $(this).val() );
  $("#img").prop("src", imageUrl[v]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" id="slider" value="0.0" min="0" max="5" step="1" />
<br /><br />
<img src="" style='width:100px;height:100px;' id='img'/>
slider value = <span id="sliderStatus">0</span>
```

Hope it helps you out.

Comment: You gave the right anwer. I had overlooked that the slider is an input.

Comment: There you go. I also deleted my post.

Comment: Hahaha yeah thanku brother it would be a great help if you mark it as an answer. :)

Comment: Unless I am making a fool of myself, I thought only the person who asked the question could mark your answer as "solved". Enlighten me please if I am wrong.

Comment: tf my bad. That's what happens when your greedy for reputations .:D. Anyways thanks brother appreciate your +ve spirits.

Comment: LOL, aren't we all?

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply. Would it be asking too much for you to give me an example with a simple image swap? I'm a better designer than a programmer, and i'm still learning Jquery. This probably the most complex thing I've attempted. 

https://codepen.io/stinkytofu3311/pen/LWomev

Comment: brother you have posted your jquery code in ur css section.

Comment: hey check my updated answer. And if it helps you out please upvote and mark it correct. Thank you.

Comment: Sachin you are a hero among men. Thank you sir. I will give this post an update on the project.